# What is an English phrase for "produktionsbedingter Leerraum"?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What is a good English phrase for "produktionsbedingter Leerraum"?

The literal meaning is "an empty space caused by production" and tells buyers that the half-empty cookie box is a feature.

Comment: Isn't your example more of a "marketingbedingter" Leerraum? ;)

Comment: The above is a common printed phrase, very likely with legal implications like "Serviervorschlag".

Comment: This and the answers remind me of the classic *this page intentionally left blank*.

Comment: Shouldn't this question belong to English.SE?

Comment: I agree that it should be on English.SE. The concept can be easily explained, so no knowledge of German is really needed.

Comment: English.SE does not want translation questions.

Comment: `This space intentionally left blank?`

Comment: `nocookies status-bydesign`

Comment: Space in box is normal. (Direct and to the point)

Comment: Die Frage soll eine Englischlücke schließen. Dass die Briten keine solche Fragen akzeptieren macht sie nicht automatisch für uns geeignet, nur weil die Personen hier vielleicht die Kompetenz haben, sie zu beantworten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technical term in the US is ["slack-fill"](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?fr=100.100), however consumers aren't likely to know what this means. (In terms of potato chips and other vacuum-packed goods, this is also called "headspace"):

> *Slack-fill is the difference between the actual capacity of a container and the volume of product contained therein.*

In order to explain this concept to consumers, you'd probably need to resort to a more descriptive sentence instead of a technical term. The other answers have provided some suggestions, although they do feel somewhat clumsy.

My additional suggestion:
Product packed with empty space for transportation.

Answer (score 4):

Such a thing doesn't appear written very often, and translating compound words tends to always produce clumsy results.

I would propose either

> Free space from manufacturing

(short for "free space resulting from the manufacturing process")

or

> Manufactured free space

As a label, perhaps

> Space left free by design

would work.

Comment: I like the last of your three proposals. How about "please excuse unavoidable void"? j/k